# keyboard shortcut to jump to the non-whitespace first character in a line

Tags: keyboard

<kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> is pretty close - it moves the character to the first column. <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>left</kbd> does too.

if my keyboard had a <kbd>home</kbd> key this would likely move the cursor there, but it doesn't.

similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/331221/jump-to-first-non-whitespace-character-in-line-in-emacs), i'm trying to get vim's <kbd>^</kbd> behaviour without moving my hands too far. unfortunately <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd> outputs µ instead of giving me the goods.

i'm hoping for something i can use system wide, i'm not sure if os x has this though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no shortcut for it by default. As a hack, you can create `~/Library/KeyBindings/` and save a property list like this as `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
{
  "~m" = (moveToBeginningOfParagraph:, insertText:, " ", moveLeft:, selectWord:, 
  moveRight:, setMark:, moveToBeginningOfParagraph:, deleteForward:, 
  swapWithMark:, moveLeft:);
}
```

Then quit and reopen applications to apply the changes. `~m` is option-m, which is bound to `back-to-indentation` in Emacs.

I copied the macro from https://github.com/ttscoff/KeyBindings/blob/master/DefaultKeyBinding.dict. `moveToBeginningOfParagraph:, selectWord:, moveRight:` would not work with lines that don't start with spaces or tabs. `moveToBeginningOfParagraph:,moveWordRight:, moveWordLeft:` would not work with some lines where the first non-whitespace character is a special character.

DefaultKeyBinding.dict does not work with some applications like Xcode or Firefox.

See http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html or http://osxnotes.net/keybindings.html for more information.

Comment: this is really eye opening - that Customizing the Cocoa Text System article is great